# Accessing Windows 7 QEMU/KVM Virtual Machine on portable via spice from another machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am running Lubuntu 13.04 on a Samsung series 9 laptop.

I installed windows 7 as a virtual machine running under qemu/kvm.

I am able to display the virtual machine from Lubuntu on the host laptop by running from the terminal `spicec -p 127.0.0.1  -h 5900`.

I would like to be able to display the virtual machine from another lubuntu workstation but cannot figure out how to do so since the 127.0.0.1 ip address is obviously the local loopback address.

I have run `arp -an` on the host machine under Lubuntu and have tried all of the addresses provided by the `arp -an` command; I either got connection refused or connection timed out.  I am not using bridging (yet) I but am instead using the virtual network default NAT with device model rtl8139.

I suspect I need to use network bridging but am concerned that since I use the laptop at both my home office, at my customer's office, and at the university (at which I teach part time) the addresses would need to be different and it would be a real pain in the neck.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to configure the qemu/kvm nat table so that I could just set the -h opicion of spicec to my laptop to a particular port that would be forwarded to the virtual machine?
- Is there some other approach I can use

Thanks . . .

Phil

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect with any of the spice clients (there are several to choose from).

```
spicec -h <host_ip_address> -p <port_number> -w <password>
```

The port numbers start with 5900 with the first guest, then 5901, etc.

If you can not connect, please be sure you have not firewalled the server or client and update your question with what client you are using.